# NGXS - Handle action life cycle in actions$ stream

Tags: angular, ngxs

In one of my states, I cannot use the `@Action(...)` annotation so I want to use the actions$ stream instead, like so

```
@State(...)
export class MyState implements NgxsOnInit {
    constructor(private actions$: Actions) {}

    ngxsOnInit(ctx: StateContext<any>): void {
        this.actions$.pipe(ofActionSuccessful(MyAsyncAction)).subscribe(() => {
            console.log('SUCCESS');
        });

        this.actions$
            .pipe(
                ofActionDispatched(MyAsyncAction),
                tap(() => console.log('DISPATCHED')),
                delay(1000),
                map(() => console.log('DONE')
            .subscribe();

    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the logs in the console looks like "DISPATCHED", "SUCCESS" and then "DONE". Is there a way to handle actions life cycle while using the actions$ stream ? Or should I go the "old" way and then use a dedicated `MyAsyncActionSuccess` action to handle this case ?

Answer (score 0):

Might be related to [this open issue](https://github.com/ngxs/store/issues/139). The library is not compatible with Redux Dev Tools. I believe NGXS is planning to ship it's own dev tools.